# bash unit tests with dynamic content

Tags: bash, unit-testing

I had to implement some new features on an very old awk script and now want to implement some unit tests to check if my script breaks things. I used diff to check if the script output is different from the whished output:

```
awk -f mygenerator.awk test.1.gen | diff - test.1.out -q
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "test failed"
fi
```

But now i have some files that generate a dynamic content like a timestamp of the generation date, which causes diff to fail because obviously the timestamp will be different.
My first though was to remove the corresponding lines with grep and test the two "clean" files. then check by egrep if the line is a timestamp.

is there any better way to do this? It should all be done by common unix tools in a bash script due to compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed` with regular expressions.

If your output is like `Fri Feb 21 22:53:54 UTC 2014` from the `date` command, use:

```
regex_timestamp="s/([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3} [0-9]{4})//g"; 
awk -f mygenerator.awk test.1.gen | diff <(sed -r "$regex_timestamp" -) <(sed -r "$regex_timestamp" test.1.out) -q
```

If you're trying to filter a unix timestamp, simply use this as regex:

```
s/([0-9]{10})//g
```

Please note that the latter replaces any group of numbers the same size as a unix timestamp. What format is your timestamp?

Comment: my timestamp has the format `(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-9]{2})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30|31) ([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `sed` to replace the timestamp with `XXXXXX`, so I can still compare the other information on the same line.

```
date | \
sed 's/\(Sun\|Mon\|Tue\|Wed\|Thu\|Fri\|Sat\) \(Jan\|Feb\|Mar\|Apr\|May\|Jun\|Jul\|Aug\|Sep\|Oct\|Nov\|Dec\)  \?[0-9]\+ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [A-Z]\+ [0-9]\{4\}/XXXXXX/'
```